# What is the difference between ST_GEOMETRY and WKT?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, well-known-text, st-geometry

What is the difference between ST_GEOMETRY and WKT? Is ST_GEOMETRY just a database type and WKT (well-known text) is a textual representation of the data?

Comment: which database are you using? Can you give some context as to where this question is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WKT is a text interchange format ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)) ([PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#RefObject)), and if you use PostGIS, you might use it like I do occasionally in SQL queries, to get a quick non-visual check on the geometry - see the [ST_AsEWKT](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) function.

ESRI seems to use 'ST_Geometry' to be the whole class of 'Spatial SQL' concepts and [functions](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_SQL_functions_used_with_ST_Geometry/006z0000003n000000/) laid out in the [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa)/[ISO](http://doesen0.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/proceedings/paper/68.pdf) standard, AND use it to be a geometry [storage type](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/What_is_the_ST_Geometry_storage_type/006z000000ws000000/), e.g. in contrast to their older closed SDEBINARY format. PostGIS seems to use it as a storage type, as you use functions like ST_[GeomFromText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html) to populate spatial columns from interchange formats. Though I can't say I've got a clue what the actual storage format in PostGIS is.

Comment: The storage format is described [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/liblwgeom/g_serialized.txt). Unless you're actually writing C code for the back-end, you never see it. Even the binary output is not the storage format, it's [extended WKB](https://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt).